# ListView Adapter does not change language when locale changes

Tags: android

So, I am creating a 2-language app. The changing of the `locale` works good on every `activity` but one. Here I have an `ListView` that's created with an `adapter` dynamically according to the `JSON` response from the server. I am using a `spinner` located on the `navigation` to switch the language like this:

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_drawer_item3).getActionView();
    SpinnerAdapterTara adapter = new SpinnerAdapterTara(this, mCountryList);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setSelection(pozitie_limba);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TaraITEM clickedItem = (TaraITEM) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String clickedCountryName = clickedItem.getCountryName();
            pozitie = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();

            if (!clickedCountryName.equals(lastCountryName)) {
                lastCountryName = clickedCountryName;
                switch (clickedCountryName) {
                    case "FR": {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SetareLimba", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("LimbaMea", "fr");
                        editor.putInt("Pozitie", pozitie);
                        editor.apply();
                        setAppLocale("fr");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Profil.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        spinner.setSelection(position);
                        break;
                    }
         
                    case "EN": {
                        setAppLocale("en");
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SetareLimba", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("LimbaMea", "en");
                        editor.putInt("Pozitie", pozitie);
                        editor.apply();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Profil.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        spinner.setSelection(position);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

When I change the language, all the `strings` switch according to the en/fr strings files, but because I use the `refresh` by `intent`, the `list` gets recreated, but with the same `default` language, `en`. So if I switch to `fr`, I get all the screen with french strings, but the `list` with english strings. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you show code of mCountryList initialization

Comment: `private ArrayList<TaraITEM> mCountryList; public  void initList() {
        mCountryList = new ArrayList<TaraITEM>();
        mCountryList.add(new TaraITEM("EN", R.drawable.steag_en));
        mCountryList.add(new TaraITEM("FR", R.drawable.steag_fr));
    }` @DineshSarma

Comment: you are using hard coded strings i.e. "EN" and "FR". To change as locale change you have to set those value from resourse file.

Comment: TaraITEM(getString(R.string.en),R.drawable.steag_en); like this

Comment: @DineshSarma That's only how it displays in my spinner.

Comment: then what do you want to be change

Comment: @DineshSarma the content of the `ListView` that's created in the page, not the one from the spinner.

Comment: from where your JSON data comes from, is it comes from server, if yes then server should return the value in specified language. your locate can not change server data

Comment: @DineshSarma of course, I am not talking about server data. I am talking about `strings` used within the `app`